# How can I disable registration in opencart 2 ?

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

How can I disable the registration, which would only have guest payment?

Answer (score 0):

As a paid option you can get this: http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=22925

Update: Sorry to say but you will have to change the code of the program and thats beyond my knowledge. or spend a little money on an extention to do it.

Sorry I coulnt be more usful.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following extensions. May be it will help you.

> http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=15213
>
> http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=22925&filter_search=guest%20checkout
>
> http://projects.remcob00.com/demos/opencart-disable-registration/